# Ubunttu Not Loading without ACPI - Asus

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I'm having a problem with my ASUS X541UA. I have an issue in which I cannot load the laptop without `acpi=off`, but in doing so I have no function of the touchpad. My original issue I had was that it was freezing when booting the live CD. I'm new to all this so I will just list what I've tried from knowledge and this site.

1. Freezing so then used `acpi=off` in grub when running through install Ubuntu live CD.
2. Fatal error "Unable to install grub in /dev/sda1" (I made a EFI partition of 550 MB) so installed bootloader through terminal then got a error stating to not forget to boot UEFI on `shimx64.efi` file.
3. Set up a boot path and it works but still have the issue of acpi having to be off. If I don't input `acpi=off` at this stage it sometimes loads but only to login screen. Thereafter it shows a blank screen doing nothing at all(tried running terminal on keyboard to see if it was just graphics).

Other common points may be, had Windows 10 previously, loading screen doesn't look right (Ring disappears sometimes), PCI bus error shows sometimes, UEFI, Intel graphics card (double checked they were updated through terminal) and also tried varieties of secure boot off and on. Tried to use the list function and failed.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to my problem. It was as simple as `pcie_aspm=off`.